# Textbox Data add i

Tags: vba, excel

this macro add data in blank active cell but i need data add in last blank row what is correct in given macro

```
Sub FillDateSenderFrom()
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Controls("TextBox" & i) <> "" Then
            If i = 1 Then
                Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, i - 1).Select
                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Value = Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
            Else
                Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
                Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Value = Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please learn to indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the last row and to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, `Activate`- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Some small working example of your code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    i = 1
    Dim myRow As Long

    If Controls("TextBox" & i) <> "" Then
        myRow = lastRow(columnToCheck:=4)
        Cells(myRow, 4) = Controls("TextBox" & i).Text    
    End If
End Sub

Function lastRow(Optional wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If wsName = vbNullString Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    End If

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

In general, if you are working on a form, it is a good idea to mention it.